# Connecting an external mic to MacBook Air (13", 2017), with MacOS 10.15.5 Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, microphone

I am trying to connect my new RODE wireless mic to my Macbook Air. Tried headphone splitters, but the computer does not recognize an external mic. (does not switch from internal to external mic). These MacAirs have USB ports and headphone jacks. So should I try a USB splitter?

Comment: What type of connector does the Røde have? See https://superuser.com/questions/1568508/pc-uses-speaker-of-headset-instead-of-microphone/1568512#1568512 and 
https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48560/recording-audio-through-3-5mm-jack-on-a-mac for some jack pinout examples.

Comment: If this is a Rode Wireless Go mic, toy need a TRS cable to connect the receiver to the Mac.

Comment: Tesujin, the RODE wireless came with the stereo type of connector.. then the splitters i bought are the third type on the link you gave (PC headset types with 3 lines)..

Comment: IconDaemon, I already got a TRS cable..

Comment: Macs use TRRS - as in the second link - so you'll need an adaptor. That type of mic is designed to plug into a camera, not a computer.

Comment: Tetsujin, thank you very much..but please watch this tutorial, which i followed.. my splitter is TRSS, the other connector (between splitter and the RODE receiver) is the TRS one.. So, do you recommend to change the TRS also to TRSS (the connector between the splitter and the mic)?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYJMiv9b_YA

Comment: is this possibly the connecting cable I need? http://en.rode.com/accessories/sc7

Comment: http://cdn1.rode.com/sc7_datasheet.pdf